# Как "поймать" маршрутизированное событие в UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, события, usercontrol, stackpanel

Ситуация такая.

У меня есть UserControl(называется NamePanel), состоящий из одного TextBox и одной Button(кнопка удалить). Здесь у меня определено RoutedEvent DeleteClick.

Дизайн:

```
            x:Name="Root">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyName}"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonDelete" Content="Delete" Click="buttonDelete_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class NamePanel : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyName", typeof(string), typeof(NamePanel), new PropertyMetadata(""));
    public string MyName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyNameProperty, value); }
    }


    public NamePanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Root.DataContext = this;
    }
    public event RoutedEventHandler DeleteClick;
    private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteClick?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Также есть другой UserControl(называется NameStack), состоящий из одного свойства IEnumerable ItemSource и методов для его обновления. В дизайне добавлены лишь ScrollViewer, а внутри него одна StackPanel. Эта StackPanel заполняется дочерними элементами из коллекции ItemSource при инициализации контрола NameStack.

Дизайн:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="MainStackPanel">
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class NameStack : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSourcee", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(NameStack), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged)));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public NameStack()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Refresh()
    {
        if (ItemsSource != null)
        {
            MainStackPanel.Children.Clear();
            foreach (var name in ItemsSource)
            {
                MainStackPanel.Children.Add(new NamePanel() { MyName = name.ToString() });
            }
        }
    }
    private static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var namestack = sender as NameStack;
        if (namestack != null)
        {
            namestack.OnItemsSourceChanged((IEnumerable)e.OldValue, (IEnumerable)e.NewValue);
            namestack.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        var oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged = oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged != null)
        {
            oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged);
        }
        var newValueINotifyCollectionChanged = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (newValueINotifyCollectionChanged != null)
        {
            newValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged);
        }
    }

    private void newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

Вопрос - как мне можно перехватить и обработать событие DeleteClick, которое может быть вызвано любым из дочерних NamePanel, внутри NameStack?

Comment: Научитесь делать привязки, сейчас вы делаете очень много лишних телодвижений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не используйете привязки данных и команды, поэтому делаете много работы вручную.

Вот простой пример юзерконтрола с кнопками удаления.

Для начала, добавьте класс команды в проект

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) 
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) 
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Он позволит удобно работать с командами

Сам юзерконтрол

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfAppDeleteableItemsControl.EditableItemsControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppDeleteableItemsControl"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                            <Button Content="X" Grid.Column="1" Margin="1" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

```cs
public partial class EditableItemsControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IList), typeof(EditableItemsControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    private ICommand _deleteCommand;
    private ICollectionView CollectionView
        => CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemsSource);

    public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get => (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public ICommand DeleteCommand => _deleteCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        ItemsSource.Remove(parameter);

        // если коллекция сама умеет обновляться, тогда не нужно делать это принудительно
        if (ItemsSource is not INotifyCollectionChanged)
            CollectionView.Refresh();
    });

    public EditableItemsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

---

Проверяем

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfAppDeleteableItemsControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppDeleteableItemsControl"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:EditableItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`ObervableCollection<T>`, реализует `INotifyCollectionChanged`

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<int> _items;

    public ObservableCollection<int> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) 
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 20));
    }
}
```

`List<T>`, не реализует `INotifyCollectionChanged`

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<int> _items;

    public List<int> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) 
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).ToList();
    }
}
```

Оба варианта работают.

Я поудалял часть элементов кнопками на картинке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из команды можно сделать `DependencyProperty`, тогда можно будет ее переопределить в окне и например выдавать запрос юзеру для подтверждения удаления. Можно и в сам контрол эту логику запихнуть, решать вам.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!